# Android thread error

Tags: android, multithreading

The thread in my application is giving a weird error on the  `myThread.start()` function specifically the start is wrong the error is "Cannot resolve symbol start" . initially i thought it was a bracket issue but when i adjust them it ends up breaking the `OnClicklistner`. The thread is suppose just suppose to make the user wait before doing a set text and then the following button will take the user to a website. Can any one see my error?

```
package com.example.trap.york_hw6;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button Cheat;
Button NextPage3;
WebView browser3;

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler handler = new Handler() {

    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        TextView statement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.snitch);
        statement.setText("Checking to see if your a cop");
    }

    ;


};

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
Handler handler2 = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        browser3.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com");
    }


};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    browser3 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webkit3);
    browser3.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser3.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    Cheat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CC);
    NextPage3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next3);
    NextPage3.setOnClickListener(this);

    Cheat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                }

                ;


                Thread myThread = new Thread(r);
            myThread.start();


            };
        }

    });


    final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 7000;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

        }

        ;


        Thread myThread2 = new Thread(r2);
            myThread2.start();

    };
}


public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
    i.putExtra("value", "I got this from MainActivity2");
    i.putExtra("value1", 5);
    startActivityForResult(i, 3);
}
}
```

Comment: One suggestion for you in my answer Trap

Answer (score 0):

You are starting thread inside wrong block. Try the code below .

```
final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 7000;
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    try {
                        wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        };
    };

    Thread myThread2 = new Thread(r2);
    myThread2.start();
```

AND

```
Cheat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                };
            };
            Thread myThread = new Thread(r);
            myThread.start();
        }

    });
```

Comment: Thank You so much everything runs perfectly now

Comment: @TrapChavez if this fixed your issue, mark the answer as answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can not initialise and start Runnable inside its block.

You can write like this.

```
Cheat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
                    while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime) {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {
                                wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                }
            };
            Thread myThread = new Thread(r);
            myThread.start();
        }
    });
```

and second one

```
  final Runnable r2 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                long futureTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 7000;
                while (System.currentTimeMillis() < futureTime) {
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            wait(futureTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }
        };
        Thread myThread2 = new Thread(r2);
        myThread2.start();
```

**Suggestion :** Also i seen your `onClick` method, i suggest you check clicked button's id before doing any action like. Because if you have multiple buttons having `OnClickListener` referring to current class, you will need to check.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.Next3:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Main4Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("value", "I got this from MainActivity2");
            i.putExtra("value1", 5);
            startActivityForResult(i, 3);
            break;
        }
    }
```